# Simplest way to clone Ubuntu image for a non-technical person

Tags: boot, hard-drive, backup, disk-image

I've built a couple of machines that need to run Ubuntu for a while.  I will be away from them and will stow them at a friend's house.

In case something happens to the OS or one of the machines, **what is the simplest way for a non-technical user to clone a backed-up image on a hard drive to another hard drive**?

I know there's clonezilla.  That is a multi-step manual process that involves special booting, etc.  So the question is about having a non-technical user clone an image from one hard drive to another, to essentially replicate a hard drive that can be booted from.

I am specifically wondering if there are external devices that can have to hard drives inserted and clone the one to another with the click of a button.  Rather, I know these devices exist, but I don't know if their cloning/copying process will be able to be booted from.

Comment: Booting from a live DVD an using `dd`

Comment: Or using gparted to copy and paste the partition from one drive to another (also booting from a live CD/USB/DVD).